# Expanding and collapsing Groups causing the user to have to click twice

Tags: excel, vba

I realize this is a little nitpicky, but if there is a solution, I'd like to know it.

In an excel worksheet, rows 4 to 6 are grouped, and the sum of them shows on row 7.

The following button code to expand and collapse the groups works fine. However, I realized that after I have used either of the buttons, when I then click on the + or - to manually expand or collapse that group (or any other group), it requires 2 clicks (wrong), instead of 1 click (correct) on the + or - sign. This leads me to believe that there might be another setting that I need to handle in the button events.

```
Private Sub Btn_Collapse_Rows_Click()
   On Error Resume Next
   Rows("7:7").EntireRow.ShowDetail = False
   On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Btn_Expand_Rows_Click()
   On Error Resume Next
   Rows("7:7").EntireRow.ShowDetail = True
   On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, nevermind. I figured it out. It was that the button still had focus, and the first click brought the focus back to the sheet, so the 2nd click actually clicked the + or -. I fixed it by adding

```
Range("A1").Select
```

at the end of the expand and collapse code.

Comment: FYI, if it's an ActiveX button, you can simply set its `TakeFocusOnClick` property to `False`.

Comment: Thank you Rory. Very useful info.